# ora-01007 variable not in select list

Tags: oracle10g

How to resolve this error. I am using Oracle 10g. Do let me know if any further information is requried.

Comment: What is the query that is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

### Root Cause :

`ora-01007` eror can occur if the number passed for the position parameter is less than one or greater than the number of variables in the `SELECT` clause in any of the following calls: `DESCRIBE, NAME, or DEFINE`.

### Action :

Determine which of the problems listed caused the problem and take appropriate action.